# Doubt on asymptotics on Apéry's sequence

Tags: solution-verification, proof-explanation, asymptotics, recurrence-relations

in the book *An introduction to difference equations* by S. Elaydi (third edition, pages 377-379) is established a result of Birkhoff and Adams that, when applied to the recurrence relation
$$(n + 2)^3 u_{n+2} − (34 n^3 + 153 n^2 + 231n + 117) u_{n + 1} + (n + 1)^3 u_n = 0$$
tells us that it has two linearly independent solutions $u_1, u_2$ such that
$$\displaystyle u_1(n) \sim \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_{1,k} \dfrac{\alpha^n n^{-3/2}}{n^k}$$
$$\displaystyle u_2(n) \sim  \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_{2,k} \dfrac{\beta^n n^{-3/2}}{n^k}$$
where $\alpha=17+12\sqrt{2}$, $\beta=17-12\sqrt{2}$ and $c_{1,0}=c_{2,0}=1$.

As in the text (nor the articles it cites) is not specified what is the definition of asymptotic expansion, I've supossed that is is the [standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_expansion#Formal_definition) one, where the asymptotic scales are $\phi_k(n)=\frac{\alpha^n n^{-3/2}}{n^k}$ and $\psi_k(n)=\frac{\beta^n n^{-3/2}}{n^k}$ respectively.

So, by the definition of asymptotic expansion we can get that
$$u_1(n)-\alpha^n n^{-3/2} = o\left( \alpha^n n^{-3/2} \right)$$
$$u_2(n)-\beta^n n^{-3/2} = o\left( \beta^n n^{-3/2} \right)$$
and then that
$$\dfrac{u_1(n)}{\alpha^n n^{-3/2}} -1 \to 0$$
$$\dfrac{u_2(n)}{\beta^n n^{-3/2}} -1 \to 0$$

That is, we get that $u_1 \sim \alpha^n n^{-3/2}$ and $u_2 \sim \beta^n n^{-3/2}$.

Now, as Apéry's sequence
$$\displaystyle b_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}^2 \binom{n+k}{k}^2$$
satisfies the difference equation and $u_1, u_2$ are linearly independente, there exists some $c_1, c_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$b_n=c_1 u_1 + c_2 u_2$$
Because $0<\beta<1$, is clear that $\beta^n n^{-3/2} \to 0$ and as $u_2 \sim \beta^n n^{-3/2}$, we get that $u_2 \to 0$.

**This then implies that $c_2=0$** (this is written in the book, and I don't know why is true).

So, we now have that $b_n=c_1u_1$, and furthermore $c_1>0$.

That is because as $\alpha>1$ then $\alpha^n n^{-3/2} \to +\infty$ and because $u_1 \sim \alpha^n n^{-3/2}$, we get that $u_1 \to \infty$, so that $u_1(n_0)>0$ for $n_0$ big enough. As $b_{n_0}>0$ we get that $c_1=b_{n_0}/u_1(n_0) >0$.

Now, because $b_n=c_1 u_1$ and $u_1 \sim \alpha^n n^{-3/2}$ we have that
$$\dfrac{b_n}{c_1 \alpha^n n^{-3/2}} = \dfrac{u_1(n)}{\alpha^n n^{-3/2}} \to 1$$
so
$$b_n \sim c_1 \alpha^n n^{-3/2}$$
with $c_1>0$, that was the result I wanted to get.

Now I have two questions:

**Question 1:** Is everything in my proof that $b_n \sim A \alpha^n n^{-3/2}$ with $A>0$ correct?

**Question 2:** How can we get that $c_2=0$ from knowing that $u_2 \to 0$?

If someone wants to see the book, here is a [link](https://es.scribd.com/document/584810197/An-Introduction-to-Difference-Equations-377-379?secret_password=9VB3Ew3IzSVJAzpwTV24) to the relevant pages about the topic I've made the questions.

Comment: An asymptotic expansion is given by Kotesovec in https://oeis.org/A005259 of the OEIS.

Comment: That does not answer any part of my question.